# Cannot hide div when document initializes with .not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good Day

I hope you can help me.

The following code does not hide the `.news` div when the page loads even though they are the very first lines of code after `$(document).ready(function(){`.

```
var news = 5;
$(".news:not(:lt("+news+"))").hide();
```

However the rest of the javascript code after these two lines works flawlessly and i do not get any js errors in the browser console either.

HTML

```
<div class='news row' >
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `:gt` selector instead of `:not:lt`

Comment: Is this to accommodate more than 1 div? if not you could give it an ID and select form this.

Comment: works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/L0n71Ldz/, is your news added dynamically?

Comment: Yes it does accomodate more than one div so i cannot use id.

Comment: Thanks Pete, i see it does work on JS fiddle, will have to look at other possible issues, thanks.

Comment: @BillClinton You have to replicate your issue on jsFiddle e.g, it could be many things that cause your issue. Firstly, check what returns `console.log($(".news").length);` at time you call your snippet?! If not what you expect as lenght, then you call it before elements added to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Your code will hide all the .news div in the page from the 6th to the end like:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var news = 5;
  $(".news:not(:lt("+news+"))").hide();
});
```

```html
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div class='news row' >
    1111111
</div>
<div class='news row' >
    2222222222222
</div>
<div class='news row' >
    33333333333333
</div>
<div class='news row' >
    44444444444444
</div>
<div class='news row' >
    5555555555555555
</div>
<div class='news row' >
    666666666666666
</div>
<div class='news row' >
    777777
</div>
<div class='news row' >
    88888888
</div>
<button id="btn">Click Me to hide</btn>
```

To hide only the first div:

```
     $(".news:eq(0)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var news = 5;
$(".news:gt("+(news-1)+")").hide();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0n71Ldz/1/)